# How to delete file and that file is used by another process using C#

Tags: c#, io, filestream, delete-file

In my C# application I want to delete file in below scenario.

1. OpenFileDialog and select any .jpg file.
2. Display that file in PictureBox.
3. Delete that file if needed.

I already try while doing step 3 I set default Image to PictureBox just before delete but that is not work.

How can I delete file? Please suggest me.

```
 // Code for select file.
 private void btnSelet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (DialogResult.OK == openFileDialog1.ShowDialog())
        {
            txtFileName.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            myPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
 }

 // Code for Delete file
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        try
        {
            //myPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Images\defaultImage.jpg");
            System.IO.File.Delete(txtFileName.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("File Delete Sucessfully");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Is your own program using that file or some other one also?

Comment: take out picture id, close dialog( or change as required). delete file with id.

Comment: ya it is my own program

Comment: Could you post your code ?

Comment: @VikasRana Rana I can't get you please explain in details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing the image sounds like a good idea - but don't forget to dispose of the old [`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx) that's still holding the file open (and will, by default, until that `Image` is garbage collected - at some unknown time in the future):

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        try
        {
            var old = myPictureBox.Image;
            myPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Images\defaultImage.jpg");
            old.Dispose();

            System.IO.File.Delete(txtFileName.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("File Delete Sucessfully");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

(It may also be possible to `Dispose` of the `Image` directly without replacing the image for the `PictureBox` - it depends on what else you're going to do after deletion - e.g. if the form on which the `PictureBox` appears is closing that you may want to let that happen first and then just directly dispose of the image).